# exponential sum over variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, exponential-sums

I am wondering where to find a good reference for bounds of the type

$$\sum_{x\in V(\mathbb{F}_p)} \chi(g(x))\psi(f(x))$$

where $V$ is a variety, $\chi$ is a multiplicative character over $\mathbb{F}_p$ and $\psi$ is an additive character over $\mathbb{F}_p$.

What conditions for V, $f$, $g$ gives what kind of bounds?

When $\chi$ or $\psi$ is trivial, what are known? Similarly, for nontrivial characters, what are known?

Comment: What are $g$ and $f$? If these are polynomials, then you presumably need to assume something like $V$ is an affine variety.

Comment: $f$ and $g$ are rational functions. I was looking for a reference where I can find such results. When can we get an nontrivial bounds? What is the most general result?

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ are only assumed rational, then how does your sum handle their singularities?

Comment: @LSpice Normally one takes the summand to be zero at the poles of $f$ and $g$, as well as at the zeroes of $g$.

Answer (score 17):

This is a very general sort of problem and you will get very different answers depending on exactly which $V, f,g$ you need.

The least savings you could ask for is $\sqrt{p}$ savings over the trivial bound, i.e $O(p^{\dim V- 1/2})$. This essentially always applies, and can be proved without reference to etale cohomology theory, by reducing to the one-dimensonal case - see the [paper of Weil](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1079093/).

The most savings you could hope for in any nontrivial case is square-root cancellation, i.e. $O(p^{ \dim V/2})$. This is expected to happen for most $V, f,g$, but nothing approaching a classification of cases where it fails is known. Instead we know a number of different results giving specific conditions, usually involving some kind of nonsingularity at infinity, that imply square-root cancellation.

Some of the most general work in this area is due to Katz. The $\chi$ trivial case is studied [here](https://web.math.princeton.edu/~nmk/ESES.pdf). The case $V = \mathbb A^n$ is studied [here](https://web.math.princeton.edu/~nmk/addmult15.pdf). I think you can find more references by following the links in those. If your case is similar to these but is not exactly covered, then perhaps the methods can be modified, and you can always use slicing to reduce to a lower-dimensional case at the cost of a somewhat weaker bound.

Often in practice you end up with a sum of this type where the polynomials do not satisfy any kind of nonsingularity condition but instead have other kinds of structure (e.g. multiplicative or additive symmetries). Then one could try to bring to bear any of the many tools of $\ell$-adic sheaf and etale cohomology theory to the problem. This is hard to summarize as it can get very messy.

Comment: Could you explain, or point to a reference, how one can reduce to the one dimensional case, if one were content with a saving of $\sqrt{p}$?

Comment: @LeoOwler For $V$ of dimension $n$, if you choose a surjection $h$ from $V$ to a variety $W$ of dimension $n-1$, the number of points of that variety is $O(p^{n-1})$ by Lang-Weill. The points $x\in V$ such that $h^{-1}(h(x))$ has dimension $>1$ have dimension $\leq n-1$ and thus there are $O(p^{n-1})$ such points by Lang-Weil. The contribution of these points is a lower-order term and can be ignored.

Comment: For each point of $W$ with $h^{-1}(W)$ of dimension $1$, the sum over $h^{-1}(W)$ can be controlled by Weil's theorem and is $O(\sqrt{p})$ unless $g$ restricted to this fiber is an $m$'th power, $m$ the order of $\chi$, and $f$ restricted to the fiber is $y^p-y$ for a function $y$.  The $O(\sqrt{p} ) \cdot O( p^{n-1})$ gives a term with $\sqrt{p}$ savings, so it suffices to show the number of fibers satisfying this degeneracy condition is $ O (p^{n-1})$.

Comment: The points of $W$ whose fibers are degenerate in this way form a constructible set so by Lang-Weil it suffices to check this doesn't hold for the generic point, which will be true as long as $g$ is not an $m$'th power or $f$ is not of the form $y^p-y$ for a function $y$, and we choose a reasonable map $h$. A reference surely exists, let me see if I remember where....

Comment: Thank you that's already very helpful. I suppose it's not entirely clear to me that we can always find such a map $h \colon V \rightarrow W$. If you do happen to have a reference where this is carried out that would be very useful. I've been looking for a while but couldn't find anything.